# Не работает \n в текстовом файле (C#)

Tags: c#, sfml

Делаю программу C# при помощи SFML. Решил сделать поддержку разных языков при помощи обычных текстовых файлов. Попытался в тексте сделать перенос строк с помощью \n:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при чтении файла при помощи StreamReader'а он выводит полную строку С \n:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как происходит чтение файла:

```
public static List<string> text = new List<string>();
public static void Load(string languageName)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + $"\\Files\\Languages\\{languageName}.txt");

            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if(line.StartsWith("//"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {

                    text.Add(line);
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Если поставить \n\r ничего не поможет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам файл:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZOCmMKdHcz3319u6ny58EWDjvMqyy0V5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: вопрос интересный, но только причина непонятна) приложите код

Comment: @finally добавил)

Comment: Environment.NewLine попробуйте

Comment: @LiptonDev тут дело в том, что я не знаю как это сделать, ведь если в тексте просто написать Environment.NewLine ничего не сделает..Буду рад, если поможете :)

Comment: Загуглили бы хоть для начала, что это такое... Пишите в файл не просто \n, а \n\r

Comment: @LiptonDev изменил описание.

Comment: Как и куда вы пишете `\n` ?

Comment: @tym32167 \n я писал вручную

Comment: куда вы это писали? В обычный текстовый файл?

Comment: @tym32167 да, в обычный .txt

Comment: почему бы вместо `\n` просто не начать новую строку в текстовом файле?

Comment: @tym32167 программа читает файл по порядку, и если бы я написал на новой строке, оно бы засчитало это как отдельную строчку, что не очень удобно :) но уже LiptonDev помог :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто, если пользоваться отладчиком VS.
После чтения из файла в строке оказывается не "\n\r", а "\\n\\r"
[image: 1]

В вашем случае достаточно заменить \\ на \ и всё будет работать.
Для моего примера можно сделать так:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Select(x => x.Replace("\\n\\r", "\n\r")).ToArray();
```

Для вашего примера с поддержкой комментариев можно сделать так:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Where(x => !x.StartsWith("//")).Select(x => x.Replace("\\n\\r", "\n\r")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы используете Escape последовательности в текстовом файле? При чтении из файла 
и последующем выводе текста файла в консоль, символ новой строки спокойной выводится как новая строка.